# How to create bar chart using QuartzCore?

Tags: ios

I'm creating an app where i need a bar chart.For a question we'll be having 4 or 5 options. I want to show the number of options selected by the users in a bar chart(like 10 members selected option A, 5 members option B etc). How to do it using Quartzcore? Please help me

Comment: use `core Plot` for creating Chart.

Comment: look at this:http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `CorePlot`, you have a good tutorial there (maybe a liitle outdated but still usable)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1
http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2

Comment: Thanks Edelweiss, but i dont want to use core plot. Is there any simple way using Quartz core.

Comment: `corePlot` uses `QuartzCore`, if you really don't want to use it you can lok at `quartz 2d` documentation on Apple doc website :  [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d) but it's really tricky and I higly recommand you to use CorePlot